# Getting images from Gallery/Camera using MVP

Tags: android, mvp

I am writing an app that allows user to either take a picture with the camera 
or choose an image in the gallery. I have a Fragment whose the layout displays 
two boutons, depending on the button pressed I use intent either to start the 
camera or open the Gallery. It works fine.

My purpose now is to do that with MVP. As I see things

- my fragment is the View
- the place from where images come from is the Model so in this case the models
  would be getting images from the gallery or with the camera
- a Presenter asks models to give him a picture and forwarding the image 
  to the fragment

The problem is model objects are Pojo classes and to retrieve an image from the 
Camera or Gallery the class needs to implement `startActivityForResult` to retrieve
the photo taken/choosed.

How can I get image from camera/gallery with a class that is not a Fragment or 
an Activity ? 
How can I move code for camera/gallery in POJO class ?
Is it overall a good idea ? I did not find any MVP examples where retrieving 
images was done out of a Fragment or an Activity ?

**Note:** Maybe is such an architecture possible with RxAndroid but I wish I could do that first without third party librairies.

Thanks for all your suggestion

Comment: What is MVP?...

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get image from camera/gallery with a class that is not a Fragment or an Activity ?

You have to do all this stuff from your presenter, not from your POJO class. Here you want to access an android resource, so pass the call back to the 'view-layer' from 'presenter-layer' and get response from system. Once the response is received in the `onActivityResult` method of Fragment/Activity, pass it into the presenter. cheers :)

Comment: good solution but the problem is: onActivityResult is called before onStart (where presenter is attached), you can attach it on onCreate of course and handle that, anyway